# How to calculate Retention rate of Userplayed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have database of UserPlayed of a mobile game containing these:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AppVersion':['1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.22','1.0.22','1.0.22','1.0.22'],
    'Level':['1','2','3','4','5','1','2','3','4','5'],
    'UserPlayed':['7131','6666','6235','5482','4779','12787','12096','11251','9750','8891']
})
```

Can anyone please show me how to calculate Retention Rate of UserPlayed groupby Appverion?
Definition:

- Retention at Level 1 = 100%,
- Retention at Level 2 = UserPlayed at Level 2 / UserPLayed at Level 1,
- Retention at Level 3 = UserPlayed of Level 3 / UserPlayed at Level 1,
- ...

Comment: Please don't post pictures and post actual examples/tables

Comment: Also how are defining/calculating retention here? Is it something like for version_i and level_i, is it `max(new_number_players/old_num_players, 100)`?

Comment: Hi @SurajShourie. At level 1 of both version, retetion = 100%, level 2 = (userplayed at level 2 / userplayed of level 1) *100 . level 3 = (userplay at level 3 / userplayed at level 1) * 100 ......

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` to keep only Level=='1' and forward fill values:

```
# Not mandatory if UserPlayed is already numeric
df['UserPlayed'] = pd.to_numeric(df['UserPlayed'])

# Assuming Level is a string (and not a number else remove quotes around '1')
lvl1 = (df.sort_values(['AppVersion', 'Level'])['UserPlayed']
          .where(df['Level'] == '1').ffill())

df['Retention'] = df['UserPlayed'] / lvl1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
0     1.0.20     1        7131   1.000000
1     1.0.20     2        6666   0.934792
2     1.0.20     3        6235   0.874351
3     1.0.20     4        5482   0.768756
4     1.0.20     5        4779   0.670172
5     1.0.22     1       12787   1.000000
6     1.0.22     2       12096   0.945961
7     1.0.22     3       11251   0.879878
8     1.0.22     4        9750   0.762493
9     1.0.22     5        8891   0.695316
```

Visualization:

```
df.pivot(index='Level', columns='AppVersion', values='Retention').plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you can use `group by` and `transform` functions to do this

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'AppVersion':['1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.20','1.0.22','1.0.22','1.0.22','1.0.22','1.0.22'], 'Level':['1','2','3','4','5','1','2','3','4','5'],'UserPlayed':['7131','6666','6235','5482','4779','12787','12096','11251','9750','8891']})

df['UserPlayed'] = df['UserPlayed'].astype(int) # convert to int
df = df.sort_values(['AppVersion', 'Level']) # sort

df = df.set_index(['AppVersion', 'Level'])
firsts = (df.groupby(level=['AppVersion']).transform('first')) # level1 data if sorted properly
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'UserPlayed': 'Retention'})
df2.merge(df, on = ['AppVersion', 'Level'])
```

Output:

| AppVersion | Level | Retention | UserPlayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0.20 | 1 | 1 | 7131 |
| 1.0.20 | 2 | 0.934792 | 6666 |
| 1.0.20 | 3 | 0.874351 | 6235 |
| 1.0.20 | 4 | 0.768756 | 5482 |
| 1.0.20 | 5 | 0.670172 | 4779 |
| 1.0.22 | 1 | 1 | 12787 |
| 1.0.22 | 2 | 0.945961 | 12096 |
| 1.0.22 | 3 | 0.879878 | 11251 |
| 1.0.22 | 4 | 0.762493 | 9750 |
| 1.0.22 | 5 | 0.695316 | 8891 |

Comment: Anyway to keep original 'UserPlayed' column and add new column 'Retention' ? 
Thank you

Comment: use pd merge and rename

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, how can we use for loops to sol my problem?

Comment: Ideally, ask a new question (after closing/accepting this one) for followups.

Comment: IF you want to use loops explicitly, explore [pd.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) but it is usually not a recommended approach. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues